# Showing that $\varphi(x)^p = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \chi_{B_k}(x)$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb R^n$ and satisfies additional property.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the function

$$\varphi(x)^p := \sum_{k=2}^\infty \chi_{B_k}(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^n,$$

where $B_k = B(2^k e_1,1)$ and $1 \leqslant p < \infty$. My goal is to show that this function belongs to $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ and also that

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, r > 0} r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)} |\varphi(y)|^p \, dy < \infty, $$

for every $0 < \lambda < n$.

**My attempt.** I think I was able to show that $\varphi \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ in the following way:

It is clear that for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ there exists some $R > 0$ such that $K \subset B(0,R)$. Therefore, we have that

$$ \int_K |\varphi(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \int_{B(0,R)} |\varphi(y)|^p \, dy = \int_{B(0,R)} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \chi_{B_k}(y) \, dy. $$

Now, let us count the number of balls $B_k$ that intersect the ball $B(0,R)$: for any ball $B_k$, the balls $B_k$ and $B(0,R)$ intersect if and only if

$$ |2^ke_1 - 0| < R + 1. $$

Solving for $k$, one obtains that the balls $B_k$ and $B(0,R)$ intersect if and only if

$$ k < \log_2(R+1).$$

Clearly, if $R < 3$, we have that $\log_2(R+1) < 2,$ which implies that the balls $B(0,R)$ and $B_k$ never intersect for any $k \geqslant 2$. So, in the case $ R < 3$ we have that

$$ \int_K |\varphi(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \int_{B(0,R)} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \chi_{B_k}(y) \, dy = 0. $$

Now suppose that $ R \geqslant 3$. In this case we've already seen that $B_k$ intersects $B(0,R)$ for every $2 \leqslant k < \log_2(R+1).$ Hence, it follows that

$$ \int_K |\varphi(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \int_{B(0,R)} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \chi_{B_k}(y) \, dy = \int_{B(0,R)} \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor \log_2(R+1) \rfloor}\chi_{B_k}(y) \, dy \leqslant \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor \log_2(R+1) \rfloor} |B(0,R)| < \infty. $$

Hence we conclude that $\varphi \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$.

But I don't know how to deal with the second property. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: @Kroki Thanks. I've added information about both $p$ and $\lambda$ in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same idea that you did for the first part, $$B_k \cap B(x, r) \neq \varnothing\; \implies \;  \left|x_1 - 2^k\right| \le  \left\|x-2^k e_1\right\| \le r + 1 \; \implies \; \left|x_1 - 2^k\right| \le r+1$$

$$\implies x_1 - (r+1) \le 2^k \le x_1 + (r+1)$$

- If $x_1 < 1$, $$B_k \cap B(x, r) \neq \varnothing\; \implies 2^k \le 1 + (r+1) \quad \implies k \le \log_2(r + 2) + 1 $$
- If $2^\ell \le x_1 < 2^{\ell + 1}$ and $2^\ell \le 2(r+1)$ then, $$B_k \cap B(x, r) \neq \varnothing\; \implies 2^k \le 2^{\ell + 1} + (r+1) \quad \implies k \le \log_2(3(r + 1))$$
- If $2^\ell \le x_1 < 2^{\ell + 1}$ and $2^\ell > 2(r+1)$ then, $$B_k \cap B(x, r) \neq \varnothing\; \implies 2^{\ell} - (r+1) \le 2^k \le 2^{\ell + 1} + (r+1)$$ in this case the number of such $k$ is bounded by \begin{align}
  \log_2(2^{\ell + 1} + (r+1)) + 1 - \log_2(2^{\ell} - (r+1))
  &= \log_2\left(2 + \frac{3(r+1)}{2^\ell - (r+1)}\right) + 1\\
  &\le \log_2 2 + \frac1{2\log(2)}\frac{3(r+1)}{2^\ell - (r+1)} + 1\\
  &\le 2 + \frac{3(r+1)}{2(r+1) - (r+1)} = 5
  \end{align}

Using the fact that $$\left|B_k \cap B(x,r)\right| \le \min \{\left|B_k\right|, \left|B(x,r)\right|\} = \left|B_1\right|\min\{1, r^n\}$$ on can prove that there is a constant $A>0$ such that for every fixed $r>0$, $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \int_{B(x,r)} \left|\varphi(y)\right|^p  
\mathrm dy \le A\left|B_1\right|\min\left\{1, r^n\right\} \log_2(r+1)$$ and you can finish the proof by using the fact that $$r \mapsto A\left|B_1\right|\min\left\{1, r^n\right\} r^{-\lambda}\log_2(r+1)$$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Can you be more detailed in the first case? I.e., why $\| x \| > r + 1$ implies that $\int_{B(x,r)} \chi_{B_k}(y) \, dy = 0$ ?

Comment: Because the intersection of $B_k$ and $B(x,r)$ is empty.

Comment: I understood that's the reason but how do you conclude that?

Comment: If you take any $r \in \mathbb{N}$, $r \geq 2$, and pick $x = 2^r e_1$, then $\|x\| = 2^r > r+1$ yet $B_r \cap B(x, r) = B_r \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Even more: in the case $\| x \| < r+1$, one has that $\sup_{r > 0} |B_1| r^{-\lambda} \log_2(r+1)$ isn't finite. For all of this to make sense one must guarantee that $r \geqslant 1$. This is the case since for $r < 1$ the balls $B_k$ and $B(x,r)$ do not intersect but either way I believe this should be explicit.

Comment: @Kroki are you thinking about editing the answer or even deleting it? It seems like this post is not getting much attention anymore and  the fact that it has been answered might be part of it.

Comment: Let me think about editing the answer the idea works fine you need just to fix it quickly.

Comment: I edited the answer should be good now.

Comment: I have **a lot** of questions. The first one is right at the start: can you add more details as to why if $\sum_{j=2}^n x_j^2 > (r+1)^2$ then the balls $B(x,r)$ and $B_k$ never intersect for any $k \geqslant 2$ ?

Comment: I added a detail about that

Comment: I removed that part because it is not needed anymore.

Comment: @TemirbekAlikhadzhiyev do you have any other question ?

Comment: @Kroki Thanks for your time and effort. I was only able to come back to this question now. I believe that I understand your reasoning but I have some questions. You start by only considering the cases where the ball $B(x,r)$ intersects at least one of the balls $B_k$: this makes sense since when there is no intersection the property is trivially satisfied. Then, you analyse different possibilites based on the values of $x_1$ (which I believe is the first coordinate of the vector $x$). I fully understood your reasoning for the case $x_1 < 1$. I wasn't able to understand the other cases.

Comment: @Kroki Perhaps you can add more details about the last two cases? When you state $2^\ell \leqslant x_1 < 2^{\ell +1}$, what do you exactly mean? This $\ell$ is an arbitrary integer? If so, how do you deduce the inequalities that follow? Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: Yes $x\ge 1$ can be seen as $1 \le x < 1$ or $2\le x < 4$ or $4 \le x < 8$ in general $2^\ell \le x < 2^{\ell + 1}

Comment: Yes, so basically you deal with $x_1 < 1$ and that's all ok. Then you analyse $x_1 \geqslant 1$ which is the same as $2^\ell \leqslant x_1 < 2^{\ell+1}$, for some $\ell \in \mathbb N$. But I don't understand how you reach your inequalities. Suppose that $2^\ell \leqslant x_1 < 2^{\ell+1}$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb N$ such that $2^\ell < 2(r+1)$. How do you guarantee that $$|x_1 - 2^k| < r+1 \implies 2^k < 2^{\ell + 1} + (r+1)?$$

Comment: When you fix your $\ell$ you have two cases for the $r$ and I am discussing the two cases

Comment: @Kroki I also understand that. I think that you're not understanding my question. Suppose that we are in the second case, i.e., there exists some $\ell \in \mathbb N$ such that $ 2^\ell \leqslant x_1 < 2^{\ell +1}$ and $2^\ell < 2(r+1)$. What I don't understand is how you conclude that $$ 2^k < 2^{\ell + 1} + r + 1$$ with these hypothesis. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I added a step at the begining of the answer to clarify the inequality

Comment: @Kroki Thanks. I still have some questions: In the case that there exists some $\ell \in \mathbb N$ such that $2^\ell \leqslant x_1 < 2^{\ell + 1}$ and $2^\ell > 2(r+1)$ I can't understand how you deduce the upper bound $4$. Can you be more detailed in these calculations? In particular, I don't agree when you state that $$ \log_2(2^{\ell +1} + (r+1)) + 1 - \log_2(2^\ell - (r+1)) = \log_2\left( 2 + \frac{2(r+1)}{2^\ell - (r+1)} \right) + 1. $$ I think you've miscalculated this.

Comment: See now If you agree

Comment: Can you add details on how you concluded that $$ \log_2\left(  2 + \frac{3(r+1)}{2^\ell - (r+1)} \right)  + 1 \leqslant 5? $$ I don't understand the inequalities you've provided in the answer.